# Error in scipy odeint use for system of ODE's

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I am trying to reproduce the two graphs shown below, which are temperature and concentration profiles as a function of time. I have checked my method and code a million times but cannot seem to find an error in it but I cannot reproduce those graphs. All values are constants except CA and T. Could it be an issue with the accuracy of odeint from scipy? Any help would be much appreciated!

The two equations are as follows:

dCA/dt = q*(CAi - CA)/V - k*CA

dT/dt = w*(Ti - T)/(V*p) + d_HR*k*CA/(p*C) + UA*(Tc - T)/(V*p*C)

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ODESolve(y, t, q, CAi, V, k0, w, Ti, p, dH_R, C, UA, Tc):

    CA, T = y
    k = k0*np.exp(8750*1/T)
    dydt = [q*(CAi - CA)/V - k*CA, w*(Ti - T)/(V*p) + \
            dH_R*k*CA/(p*C) + UA*(Tc - T)/(V*p*C)]

    return dydt

q = 100
CAi = 1.0
V = 100
p = 1000
C = .239
dH_R = 5*(10**4)
k0 = 7.2*(10**10)
UA = 5*10**4
CA0 = .5
T0 = 350
Ti = T0 
w = p*q 

y0 = [CA0, T0]
t = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)

Tc = 305
sol1 = odeint(ODESolve, y0, t, args = (q, CAi, V, k0, w, Ti, p, dH_R, C, UA, Tc))

Tc = 300
sol2 = odeint(ODESolve, y0, t, args = (q, CAi, V, k0, w, Ti, p, dH_R, C, UA, Tc))

Tc = 290
sol3 = odeint(ODESolve, y0, t, args = (q, CAi, V, k0, w, Ti, p, dH_R, C, UA, Tc))

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t, sol1[:,0], label = 'Tc = 305')
plt.plot(t, sol2[:,0], label = 'Tc = 300')
plt.plot(t, sol3[:,0], label = 'Tc = 290')
plt.ylim(ymax = 1, ymin = 0)
plt.title ('CA(t)')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t, sol1[:,1], label = 'Tc = 305')
plt.plot(t, sol2[:,1], label = 'Tc = 300')
plt.plot(t, sol3[:,1], label = 'Tc = 290')
plt.ylim(ymax = 450, ymin = 300)
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.title ('T(t)')

plt.show()
```

Here is what the graphs are supposed to produce:

[image]

And here is the output of my code above:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Double check this formula: `k = k0*np.exp(8750*1/T)`.  In a complete shot-in-the-dark, I changed the sign inside the exponential, so `k = k0*np.exp(-8750*1/T)`, and got results that look similar to the expected plots that you show.

Comment: You are a god... That is totally right! Wow, what a relief. If you submit this as an answer I'd be more than  happy to submit your response as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: OK, answer submitted.

Comment: *"You are a god... "* [Sshhh!](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/428/224/052.jpg)  [Or, maybe I'm not a god.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f8/Internet_dog.jpg)

Comment: (additionally:) With automatic type guessing in python it may be crucial to always mark floating point values as such. Thus instead of `T0 = 350` use `T0 = 350.0` etc. Hidden integer division may lead to unexpected errors or results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a sign error in the formula `k = k0*np.exp(8750*1/T)`.  If you change that to `k = k0*np.exp(-8750*1/T)`, you'll get plots like those you expect.